# Get form input value on button submit

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react,

I am trying to fetch all input values in form data using ReactJS

form.js

```
  <Form>
             
                <h6 className="heading-small text-muted mb-4">
                  Account Information
                </h6>
                <div className="pl-lg-4">
                  <Row>
                    <Col lg="12">
                      <FormGroup>
                        <label
                          className="form-control-label"
                          htmlFor="input-username"
                        >
                          Account Name
                        </label>
                        <Input
                          className="form-control-alternative"
                          defaultValue="lucky.jesse"
                          id="input-username"
                          placeholder="Username"
                          type="text"
                        />
                      </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                 
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                  <Col lg="6">
                      <FormGroup>
                        <label
                          className="form-control-label"
                          htmlFor="input-email"
                        >
                          Email address
                        </label>
                        <Input
                          className="form-control-alternative"
                          id="input-email"
                          placeholder="jesse@example.com"
                          type="email"
                        />
                 
                    </Row>
               
              </Form>
      <Button
                    color="success"
                    href="#pablo"
                    onClick={save}
                    
                  >
                    Save
                  </Button>
```

When I click on button Save, I need to retrieve all the input valuesa and form an json for API process

function code:

```
function save(e){
  alert('ok')
  //(Javascript code)
const title = document.getElementById('input-username').value
//reactcode
console.log(title);

}
```

How to fetch all form data within an function using react.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [val, setVal] = useState()

<input
   value={val}
   onChange={(e)=>setVal(e.target.value)}
/>

<button onClick={()=>console.log(val)}>Click</button>
```